# Is it possible to access classes in another target WITHOUT importing that target in Xcode?

Tags: swift, xcode

In my test project, I created 2 targets like so:

Step 1:

[image]

Step 2:

[image]

Step 3:

[image]

Afterwards, I created `TestClass1.swift` in "TestTarget1" and `TestClass2.swift` in "TestTarget2":

```
// TestClass1
public TestClass1 {
    public static var randomNumber: Int {
        return Int.random(in: 1...100)
    }
}
```

And in `TestClass2`, I wish to access the random number generator in `TestClass1` WITHOUT having to import target "TestTarget1", is this doable? e.g., by linking libraries, frameworks, etc.

You might wonder, "Why do you not want to import it?" It's very hard to explain, and I believe you don't really care, I just wonder if this is doable. Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For each source file in your project, you can choose the targets in which it is included. It is called "Target Membership" in the File Inspector in the right sidebar.

[image]

Comment: Perfect, it works! But, What if I have 10,000 files (classes) in "TestTarget1" and I'd like to access all of them in "TestTarget2"? Is there a faster way to expose all classes without having to do this one by one?

Comment: You can select all the files in the project navigator and then edit the target memberships for all of them at the same time. Alternatively you can navigate to the project > Build Phases > Compile Sources and add them there (by using the plus-button, or by dragging the files into the list).